# Difference between Oracle forms and E-business suite

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

What is the difference between Oracle forms and Oracle E-business suite?
Is there any similarities between Oracle 11G and Oracle E-business suite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle Forms is a 4GL for building applications. One of those applications is Oracle E-Business Suite (even after fifteen years of JDeveloper, ADF and Fusion Apps). So the relationship is Lego bricks vs finished model.

We can use Forms to extend Oracle EBS and/or to build our own applications.